# CPU LED on motherboard and need to reinstall processor every cold boot

Tags: boot, cpu, motherboard, power-supply

Specs:
Aorus B550 Pro Ax Rev.1
5600x
MSI gaming x 3060ti
16GB single stick 3666MHz

A few days ago, I had an electricity cut suddenly. The computer shut down.
After the electricity came back, I tried to start the computer.

The red CPU LED on the motherboard was on. The RAM turned on, the fans spun. But the system won't boot and the CPU LED persisted.

I went to a friend who has a 2600x and we just swapped processors and both our systems worked and I thought that might have somehow fixed the problem. We swapped the processors to original computers, and my computer booted as well.

Two days ago, I shutdown the computer again, normally so from windows power options.

Now the problem was back, CPU LED on motherboard is on, fans and RAM lit but no boot.

I removed the processor, and just reinstalled it, and it now boots?

Ever since every time I have to boot after a few hours or so of keeping the computer off, I have to remove the processor, repaste it, and install it on the mobo everytime :(

I have no clue why this is happening, I have shifted to a very far away town for now with limited to no tech support or computer hardware shops and the only way I can turn on my computer now is by reinstalling my processor every time.

And a new thing has started to appear. Now after booting by reinstalling the processor, VGA LED stays on, even though everything works fine. To fix this. I boot into windows by re installing processor, then I just do a soft restart from windows power options. It causes the motherboard to do a POST and it checks all 4 LEDs one by one and it starts normally for that time with no LEDs on and regular functionality.

Nothing is not working after the computer actually starts though. I can game for as long as I need which I confirmed by AFKing csgo, valorant DMs, Minecraft, Fortnite with hardware ray tracing etc for a whole day yesterday and it didn't shutdown or anything at all.

Comment: So, boots after removin and reinstallin CPU. I assume that while doing so you also unplugged power.  Can you confirm that unplugging PSU and pressing power on while unplugged, then reconnecting power does not also solve it?  (trying to isolate if PSU was damaged).  Similar question. fail to boot after full shutdown?  Or after hibernate-shutdown (fastboot?).